# Linux - Remote command execution and .bashrc

Tags: linux, bash, command, execution

I have a number of custom aliases on a Linux host (a) and when I am trying to execute some commands from another Linux host (b), the entries in ~/.bashrc complain that those commands cannot be found. Can you please explain how to avoid those errors.

Please refer to the example below.

from (b) to (a)

```
[root@localhost /]# sshpass -p 'my_pass' ssh -p port_number root@host "uptime"

/root/.bashrc: line 17: hello1: command not found

/root/.bashrc: line 18: hello2: command not found

/root/.bashrc: line 19: hello3: command not found

03:05:56 up 3 days, 23:29,  1 user,  load average: 1.16, 0.78, 0.47
```

Please advise, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This is normal, as the ~/.bashrc on your remote and host machines are not the same if you changed the ~/.bashrc on your machine but not on your remote machine. One way would just copy the different lines from your host machine ~/.bashrc to your remote one. 
If you do that you'll be able to use your aliases that you defined on your host machine in your remote machine.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I have added the same entries in both servers but I still get the command not found error. Anything else I can try?

Comment: Hummm strange, maybe when you're on the remote server you can try to execute the following:
`source ~/.bashrc` this will load all the aliases in .bashrc

Comment: I just noticed that the lines in .bashrc which have the issue include a variable, for example,

alias show_total="echo -e; echo 'Total machines running: '$(allmachines | wc -l)"

but the alias allmachines, works fine...something when retrieving the variable...

Comment: I think since what is in `$(allmachines | wc -l)` is a command you need to put a semicolon after the last command launched: `echo 'Total machines running: '`, or `&&` or  `||`.